# Can we download files in same time with URLSessionDelegate methods in multiples UIViewController separately in swift

Tags: swift

```
// Stores downloaded file
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    // 1
    guard let sourceURL = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else { return }
    let download = downloadService.activeDownloads[sourceURL]
    downloadService.activeDownloads[sourceURL] = nil
    // 2
    let destinationURL = localFilePath(for: sourceURL)
    print(destinationURL)
    // 3
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    try? fileManager.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
    do {
      try fileManager.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
      download?.track.downloaded = true
    } catch let error {
      print("Could not copy file to disk: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    // 4
    if let index = download?.track.index {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
      }
    }
  }

  // Updates progress info
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64,
    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    // 1
    guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url,
      let download = downloadService.activeDownloads[url]  else { return }
    // 2
    download.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    // 3
    let totalSize = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalBytesExpectedToWrite,
      countStyle: .file)
    // 4
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let trackCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: download.track.index,
        section: 0)) as? TrackCell {
        trackCell.updateDisplay(progress: download.progress, totalSize: totalSize)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the basic idea is to decouple your `URLSessionDelegate` from your `UIViewController` and provide a mechanism by which the `URLSessionDelegate` can inform whomever is interested with the appropriate updates as the delegate methods are called.

My preferred pattern is to create a custom shared session manager and then have it inform view controllers (or whomever initiated the download) of updates. There are a variety of different mechanisms for informing the view controllers that you could pursue:

- Have the `URLSessionDelegate` maintain an collection of `didWrite` and `didFinish` closures (and whatever else you want) keyed by task identifiers (or URL), e.g.:

  ```
  private var didWriteClosures: [Int: (URLSession, URLSessionDownloadTask, Int64, Int64, Int64) -> Void] = [:]
  private var didFinishClosures: [Int: (URLSession, URLSessionDownloadTask, URL) -> Void] = [:]
  ```

  When a particular view controller initiates a download, it passes closures which the session manager will save in these collections. And when the main session manager gets a callback on one of the `URLSessionDelegate` methods, it grabs the task identifier and optionally calls the correct closure.
- Similar to the above approach, you could adopt your own delegate-protocol pattern between the main `URLSessionDelegate` with whomever initiated the request. Then, the main `URLSessionDelegate` could maintain a collection of these delegate references, again keyed by task identifier (or URL).
- Have `URLSessionDelegate` posting notifications on `NotificationCenter` and have the view controller then observe those notifications.

Personally, for simple interfaces where I'm concerned about only two or three delegate methods, I'll use the first approach. I tend to use the second approach when I suspect I'll need some much larger subset of `URLSessionTaskDelegate` family of protocols, then I'll adopt the delegate approach.

Comment: Bro...really thank you so much....i want to mark this as useful....but right now I don't have enough reputation